# Translating a phrase using a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm attempting to translate a phrase using a dictionary by matching each word in that phrase with a dictionary's key.

http://paste.org/62195

I can translate it just well through the interactive shell, but when it comes to the actual code:

```
def translate(dict):
    'dict ==> string, provides a translation of a typed phrase'
    string = 'Hello'
    phrase = input('Enter a phrase: ')
    if string in phrase:
         if string in dict:
            answer = phrase.replace(string, dict[string])
            return answer
```

I'm not sure what to set string to that would check for anything other than 'Hello.'

Comment: Why are you using `string` at all?  Why not just apply the translation directly on the user's input?

Comment: Using `replace` is only going to lead to trouble: `hello` is a substring of `Othello`, and so you could get "Othola" if you included the lowercase version too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As guys mentioned replace is not a good idea since it matches partial words.

Here is a workaround using lists.

```
def translate(translation_map):
    #use raw input and split the sentence into a list of words
    input_list = raw_input('Enter a phrase: ').split()
    output_list = []

    #iterate the input words and append translation
    #(or word if no translation) to the output
    for word in input_list:
        translation = translation_map.get(word)
        output_list.append(translation if translation else word)

    #convert output list back to string
    return ' '.join(output_list)
```

As suggested by @TShepang it is a good practice to avoid using built_in names such as string and dict as variable names.

Comment: maybe advice Asker to avoid built-in names as generic identifiers; in this case `dict`

Comment: @jurgenreza: Thank you very much. I was thinking of using split but really couldn't figure out how to write it.

Comment: @Tshepang thanks for mentioning that, ironically the dict here is a real dictionary though. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *ironically the dict here is a real dictionary though*.

Comment: @Tshepang Maybe I should have said 'coincidentally' instead of 'ironically'. I meant the python dict is used for storing the data of a real world dictionary of words and translations.