# How can I translate from one file to another using a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a variable dictionary in this form:
`dictionary = {'hello':hola', 'good night':'buenos nochas'}`

My question is, how can I use this dictionary to translate from one file to another one, where my input is a file in English?

I know about using keys and values, but my output isn't what I was thinking it would be.  My code translates some words in the middle of them if this word is in build_dictionary.

Code:

```
dictionary_words = open("dict.txt" , "r").readlines()

x = []
t = []
for line in dictionary_words:
    words= line.split()
    x.append(besede[0])
    t.append(besede[1])
build_dictionary = dict(zip(x,t))

text = open('text.txt', mode = 'r').read()

for key in build_dictionary.keys():
    text = build_dictionary.replace(key,slovar[key])

output = open('translation.txt', mode = 'w')
output.write(text)
output.close
```

Comment: There is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232877/translating-a-phrase-using-a-dictionary

Comment: For this kind of translation, you might want to use a [Trie](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: What is the output that you are getting? And what you expect to get?

Comment: Well, this is a rather complex question. You should start asking yourself the question "how do I defined entities to be translated"? words? groups of words? if you translate "good" as "bueno", you will have problems translating "good night". If even google hasn't managed to create a reliable translator, you can imagine how crazily complicated this must be.

Comment: It doesnt have to be perfect, but it must traslate word by word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way you're using the dictionary seems a little off in the first place. When you're doing the translation, you're looping through the keys, then doing a replace. The name of the python type *is* dictionary...so why not use it as such?

For example, you build your dictionary which is a mapping of:

```
{'untranslated_word' : 'translated_word'}
```

From there, you do a `my_dictionary['untranslated_word']` and it will return `translated_word`. Then, you'll just want to loop through each word, and do that right?

Also, to safeguard against exceptions for unknown words, you could do `my_dictionary.get(word, 'UNKNOWN_WORD')`. This will return `UNKNOWN_WORD` for any values not in your dictionary.

Here's an (untested) code snippet doing the above; hopefully it gets you on the right track:

```
dictionary = {}
with open('dict.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        split_line = line.split()
        dictionary[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]

with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            for word in line.split():
                output_file.write(dictionary.get(word.lower(), 'UNKNOWN_WORD'))
                output_file.write(' ')
            output_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: I get an error fot line where is UNKNOWN WORD and an error in line output_file.write(' ')

Comment: Like I said...untested, but should get you on the right path.  Fixed it anyway though; please try again. Had an extra close paren.

Comment: Its better, i will try to improve it! And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your build_dictionary is something like d = {"today":"dia"} Try this using re.sub

```
import re
pattern = '\b%s\b'

for key in d.keys():
    text = re.sub(pattern % key, d[key], text)
```

My testing:

```
In [49]: text = "today, day"

In [50]: for key in d.keys():
   ....:     text = re.sub(pattern % key, d[key], text)
   ....:     

In [51]: text
Out[51]: 'today, dia'
```

Comment: Yes,youre right, i did forgot to repair the code here....actualy i have build_dictionary

Comment: And are you replacing the text as the code I wrote instead the build_dictionary? What output does it gives?

Comment: Having this variable text = "hola que tal hola hola adios hola" and this dictionary d = {"hola":"hello"} this little code is working fine for me In [29]: `for key in d.keys():
    if str(key) in text:
        text = text.replace(key, d[key])`
`In [30]: text
Out[30]: 'hello que tal hello hello adios hello'`

Comment: Yes, i do replace it this way. The main problem is,if i for example have this words in file i want to translate: Today and day. Then it trasnlates the day word, not Today. build_dict = {'Today:'hoy', 'day:'dia'} It should look only for the whole words.....

Comment: Still have the problem

Comment: my dictionary is: {'i': 'jaz', 'is': 'je', 'work': 'delam', 'very': 'zelo', 'Today': 'danes'} Input text is: Today is very i. i work Today and Output is: danes jazs zelo jaz. jaz delam danes, and its wrong if u take a closer look into dictionary

Comment: Oh I see the problem, I didnt undestand. Yes, you cant use replace, are your words separated by empty spaces, comma, dots, etc? if they are just separated by empty spaces you can define your dictionary like {' i ': 'jaz', ' is ': 'je', ' work ': 'delam', ' very ': 'zelo', ' Today ': 'danes'} or you can use regex using the re.sub() method https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html because the replace wont work

Comment: Yes,my words are separated by empty spaces. But there are also commas in the original file. So how do i have to define my dictionary? Didnt understand this good,sorry. And tnx Now i see you added some spaces......but my problem here is,because i build my dictionary from file,have to add spaces with code somehow......or do the translation thing on the other way

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible solution using regex instead string replacing which was giving you problems